# Fixing Version skew between master and worker node

Tags: kubernetes

I have set up a small kubernetes manually using kubeadm for learning/proof of concept apps. Unfortunately one of my nodes has a different version when I list the nodes:

```
kubectl get nodes
k8s-master   Ready    master   8h    v1.16.2
k8s-node1    Ready    worker   51m   v1.16.2
k8s-node2    Ready    worker   30m   v1.15.2
k8s-node3    Ready    worker   15m   v1.16.2
```

k8s-node2 has version v1.15.2 whereas the other nodes have version v1.16.2.
How can I get node2 up to date with version v1.16.2?
It was not clear whether I run commands on the master or the worker node to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to upgrade the `kubelet` then restart it. How you do it depends on how you installed it initially.

Answer (score 1):

According to  [Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/)  about version skew policy:

> #### kubelet
>
> `kubelet`  must not be newer than  `kube-apiserver`, and may be up to two minor versions older.
>
> Example:
>
> - `kube-apiserver`  is at  **1.13**
> - `kubelet`  is supported at  **1.13**,  **1.12**, and  **1.11**

That means that with master node `v1.16.2`, worker node with version `v1.15.2` is supported. **Your cluster is properly configured.**

However, if You decide to upgrade node to match the rest of the cluster I suggest following this [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/).